# Pulse audio problems if I start its mixer/controls `pavucontrol`

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio

I have a very strange problem in a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04. Audio output/input **works fine** in all programs, but if I open the Pulse mixer/controls **`pavucontrol`** (for example, from the sound menu in the desktop panel) **the sound stops working**. `pavucontrol` displays fine and looks like it's working. But from that moment all programs cannot access audio and therefore (for example Firefox on YouTube) they freeze, or (as VLC) they do not start at all. Additional, if I close and then restart `pavucontrol` again, it hangs displaying only the text *"Establishing connection to PulseAudio. Please wait..."*.

Also, it's impossible then to log my user out, it just do not work, it does nothing. I bet there's something freezed somewhere that the system can't manage to stop. So the only way I have to have audio back is to reboot the PC.

I tried to run:

```
pulseaudio --check
pulseaudio -D
```

The first runs fine but outputs nothing, and the second says *"Cannot start deamon"* (or something like that, it's localized, I'm in Italy).

ATM I can avoid opening `pavucontrol` so I have no problems at all. In fact, the main volume slider integrated in the audio popup-menu works fine. But I would like to solve that problem because I sometimes need to adjust the microphone volume, for example. I do not know where to start looking for logs related to audio and Pulse, so for now I cannot give you more detailed informations.

Comment: You can install and use gnome-alsamixer or directly alsamixer in a terminal

Comment: Does it work with Pulse? I know Pulse is made on top of ALSA, but... It works ok! I keep it as a workaround, but I do not consider my problem solved :)

Comment: I also appear to be experiencing this problem. It would be really nice to resolve it, because pavucontrol does more than just adjust levels - it allows me to "route" certain applications to certain outputs, for example: my video player to HDMI, Skype to my USB headset and music to speakers.

Comment: Same problem here, if I open pavucontrol then after around 20sec pulseaudio crashes and restarts itself

Comment: @BrunoBossola Hi there. Are you using Ubuntu 14.04? I'm currently using 15.10, and most of audio problems, including this one, have disappeared.

Comment: Yes, 14.04.5 LTS